# Dynamic ajax content, back button, url change & refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic

If I load the ajaxpage, I want:

- To be able to refresh the page without getting back to index.
- To make the URL change when I load the ajaxpage
- To be able to press the back button to go to previous ajaxpage
- To be able to press the forward button to go to the next ajaxpage

I've been searching for hours, but I don't understand how to use history api, and I don't know how  to include it. 
Take a look at [thishabbo.com](http://www.thishabbo.com) or [habbox.com](http://www.habbox.com), press some links in their navigation, that's exactly the behavior which I want.

Comment: The History API is exactly what you need. Specifically, what don't you understand about it? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know where I should put it, where in the code.